# How to add ListBox selection information to a Subform/Table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form `frmParts` with a ListBox `lstResults` that is being populated with a query `qryParts`. This shows many records with information like No, Description, and Cost.

I would like to have the user double click a part record from `lstResults` and auto populate a subform `sfrmKit`, i.e. **copy** the part information from `qryParts` and fill `sfrmKit`.

Once `sfrmKit` is populated with corresponding part information, the user can change the quantity and total costs can be calculated along with other information.

Is this possible or is there a better approach to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be along the lines of what I'm looking for but I'm not sure how to modify the code to my database. Here is what I have done so far: `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO sfrmKit ([Item No], [Description], [Unit Cost]) SELECT [No], [Description], [Last Direct Cost] FROM qryParts WHERE [Item No] = " & Me.[No]'` But I get an error _...Can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression_.

Comment: You insert into a table, not a form. Then apply filter to form to retrieve that set of records.

Comment: Why duplicate description info? I can understand saving unit cost because pricing can change but does description?

Comment: Description would not necessarily change but I would like to display it for the user to see so they know which part they are adding

Comment: Not necessary to save value just to have it displayed. There are other ways to display related data other than duplicating and occupying storage space in db.